# If a homogeneous multivariate polynomial is zero at all points, is it necessarily the zero polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

A very stupid question:

If a homogeneous polynomial $P(x_1,\cdots,x_k)=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^k$ then does that mean it is the zero polynomial? (I have proven this using induction but I suspect this is something rather trivial and perhaps comes from fundamental theorem).

Comment: I think the best way to show this is by induction, certainly the way you proceeded.

Comment: Yes. Prove by induction on $k$.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. Is this a well-known existing result and if yes where can I find a citation (I looked for it but couldn't find it)? I actually need to use this somewhere, and I've proven it but I'd just use the citation if it's already there. Thanks so much again.